# GetWindowText in c# returns a rectangles instead of text

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I have code like this:

```
IntPtr hwndGetValue = new IntPtr(67904);
List<IntPtr> windows = GetChildWindows(hwndGetValue);

int textLength = GetWindowTextLength(windows[0]);
StringBuilder outText = new StringBuilder(textLength + 1);
int a = GetWindowText(windows[0], outText, outText.Capacity);
```

in windows I have 49 pointers. Windows[0] have text which I can see in Spy++ but method GetWindowText return in outText rectangles instead of this text. I get {慬潹瑵潃瑮潲ㅬ} (in Visual and notepad this chinese signs are displayed as rectangles. I have something wrong with encoding ?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These symptoms indicate that you are calling the ANSI version of `GetWindowText` but interpreting the returned value as Unicode.

The solution is to make sure you call the Unicode version of `GetWindowText` instead. Do this by specifying `Charset=Charset.Unicode` in your `DllImport`.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString,
    int nMaxCount);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, this problem was driving me insane. Changing the CharSet from ´CharSet.Auto´ to ´CharSet.Unicode´ did the trick!